# Denseness of algebraic and transcendental elements in R [NBHM 2014]

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Which of the following statements are true?
a. Algebraic numbers over Z are dense in R.
b. Transcendental numbers over Z are dense in R.

Let me write what I did.
For a), the concerned set is a subset of Q and so is dense in R.
For b), I've constructed a set A={n/(π^m) : n is in Z ans m is in N} (mimicking the way we construct dyadic rationals). Then since π is transcendental over Q, it is so over Z. And so the elements of A are transcendental over Z (I've a little doubt here). The way we show that the set of dyadic rationals is dense in R, we can show that A is dense in R. Since A is a subset of the concerned set, it is also dense in R.
Am I correct? I'll be very glad if someone verifies it. Thank you. :-)

Comment: For a), it's **not** a subset of the rationals; the rationals are a subset of the algebraics. Which is what you need, anyway. What's NBHM?

Comment: Sorry,I wanted to mean that only! :P

Comment: National Board of Higher Mathematics (India). They conduct PhD scholarship Screening Test. The above question is from that test.

Comment: Sir, what about option b?

Comment: What is your definition of transcendental? What can you say about the complement of a countable subset of $\Bbb{R}$

Comment: b is fine. ${}$

Comment: @Nimda, complement of countable subset of R is uncountable. But i don't get your hint. 
(Transcendental number over Z is a real number that does not satisfy any polynomial over Z)

Comment: The complement of a countable set in $\Bbb{R}$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}$. Hint: the cardinality of an open subset is more than countable.

Comment: Yes, I can see that. Open intervals are uncountable and hence they cannot totally lie inside a countable set! 
Now I'll have to show that the set of all algebraic numbers over Z in countable. I think, it follows from the fact that set of all polynomials with natural coefficients is countable and for each polynomial we get finite number of algebraic numbers. So it is a countable union of finite sets which is countable! Am I right?

Comment: And thank you so much. Loved your hints! :-)